# SwipeView don't scrolling in vertical

Tags: qt, qml, scrollbar, qtquickcontrols2, swipeview

I have the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834681/android-realviewswitcher-dont-scrolling-in-vertical) one, but with Qt and QML.

I want to be able to swipe horizontally, but also scroll vertically on certain pages with a scrollbar, so that users can e.g. submit a form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QML - Vertical Swipe View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507444/qml-vertical-swipe-view)

Comment: It's a different problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Flickable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html) with an [attached `ScrollBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#attaching-scrollbar-to-a-flickable):

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 300
    visible: true

    SwipeView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            Text {
                text: "Page 1"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }

        Flickable {
            id: listView
            contentWidth: width
            contentHeight: pane.implicitHeight

            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}

            Pane {
                id: pane

                GridLayout {
                    columnSpacing: 10
                    columns: 2
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    Label { text: "Label" }
                    Button { text: "Button" }

                    Label { text: "Label" }
                    RadioButton { text: "RadioButton" }

                    Label { text: "Label" }
                    ComboBox { model: 100 }

                    Label { text: "Label" }
                    Button { text: "Button" }

                    Label { text: "Label" }
                    RadioButton { text: "RadioButton" }

                    Label { text: "Label" }
                    ComboBox { model: 100 }

                    Label { text: "Label" }
                    Button { text: "Button" }

                    Label { text: "Label" }
                    RadioButton { text: "RadioButton" }

                    Label { text: "Label" }
                    ComboBox { model: 100 }
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            visible: SwipeView.isCurrentItem

            Text {
                text: "Page 3"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```